# Effiecient implementation of conv2 (valid) in image_data

Tags: matlab, convolution, hardware

I'm trying to implement the `conv2` (2D convolution function in MATLAB) with the `'valid'` argument which return only parts of the convolution that are computed without zero-padded edges, meaning the kernel does not scan beyond the input.

I have this code so far which works but it seems to be needlessly complex as you can see, and I plan on converting to to fixed point and implementing it on hardware later, and the `SampleWindow` variable keeps causing me trouble because the coder assigns a dynamic matrix to it.

So I'm looking for a simpler and/or efficient implementation of the function.

```
function outConvAcc = convn(input, kernel, S)
% Get the input size in terms of rows and cols. The weights should have
% same depth as the input volume(image)
[rowsIn, colsIn, depthInput] = size(input);


% Get the kernel size, considering a square kernel always
F = size(kernel,1);
kernelf=rot90(squeeze(kernel),2);
%% Initialize outputs
sizeRowsOut = ((rowsIn-F)/S) + 1;
sizeColsOut = ((colsIn-F)/S) + 1;
outConvAcc = zeros(sizeRowsOut , sizeColsOut, depthInput);

%% Do the convolution
% Convolve each channel on the input with it's respective kernel channel,
% at the end sum all the channel results.

for r=1:S:(rowsIn-1)
    for c=1:S:(colsIn-1)
        % Avoid sampling out of the image.
        if (((c+F)-1) <= colsIn) && (((r+F)-1) <= rowsIn)
            % Select window on input volume (patch)
            sampleWindow = input(r:(r+F)-1,c:(c+F)-1);
            % Do the dot product                
            dotProd =(sampleWindow(:) .* kernelf(:));
            n=size(dotProd,1);
            dotProdc=0;
            for km=1:n   % Replace function Sum for code generation
            dotProdc=dotProd(km)+dotProdc;
            end
            % Store result
            outConvAcc(ceil(r/S),ceil(c/S),depthInput) = dotProdc;
        end
    end
end
end
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Efficient convolutions usually involve FFT which avoid using the double nested loop you have.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki As much as I agree that an efficient convolution usually involve `fft` or `fft2` in this case, it does not remove the double nested loop, it just hides them in the `fft`. The main benefit is that one of the loops is smaller in the manner as `fft` is faster than `dft` (which I guess does not exist in MATLAB).

Comment: why not loop on `r=1:S:min(rowsIn-1,rowsIn+1-F)` (or assuming F>=2, `r=1:S:rowsIn+1-F`) rather than doing a loop then starting the iteration with an `if` on counter value? Other than that, I do not see much needless complexity if the final purpose is to convert that code to *C* or another low level language.

Comment: @NickyMattsson Also, hiding the loop in the `fft` means the loop is done internally (in C probably), which is faster than doing explicitly in Matlab

Comment: @LuisMendo Indeed, my point was simply that the loops was not gone per se..

Comment: @NickyMattsson it changes the loop which is the point. Nothing really ever has "no loops", IDK, the operating system is looping to get this code running I guess. But FFT does remove the double nested loop seen here by doing something else, which also happen to have loops, but better ones

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: Convolutions through the FFT cost `K1*n+k2*n*log2(n)`, with `n` the number of pixels. Direct implementations cost `n*m`, with `m` the number of pixels in the kernel. As long as `m < K1+K2*log2(n)`, the direct implementation is faster. `K2` is a reasonably large constant here. For small `m`, it is not at all efficient to go through the FFT.

Comment: @CrisLuengo agree, the number of operations may be smaller with direct implementation for small images and/or kernels. However here we also have to count the efficiency of a compiled FFT implementation vs the efficiency of interpreted Matlab loops. My comment was referring to the usual approach when dealing with kernel convolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if the image doesn't divide evenly by `S` you get an error. You need to add `floor` here:

```
sizeRowsOut = floor((rowsIn-F)/S) + 1;
sizeColsOut = floor((colsIn-F)/S) + 1;
```

---

The main double-loop can be simplified a little bit. Instead of looping over the input image in steps of `S`, and computing the location in the output image by dividing by `S`, loop over the output image, then compute the location in the input image:

```
for r=1:sizeRowsOut
    r_in = (r-1)*S;      % NOTE! the actual location is r_in+1
    for c=1:sizeColsOut
        c_in = (c-1)*S;
        sampleWindow = input(r_in+(1:F),c_in+(1:F));
        % ...
        outConvAcc(r,c,depthInput) = dotProdc;
    end
end
```

(Note that all this indexing looks a little tidier with 0-based indexing, but alas.)

Here, you don't need the `if` any more. `input` is guaranteed to be large enough to fit that kernel, by the way that the indices are computed.

---

Next, you need to be aware of the order of data in memory, and loop such that you access the data in that order. This optimizes cache usage. MATLAB is [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), meaning that each column is stored consecutively. Your inner loop goes along a row (across columns), meaning you are looping in the wrong order. Simply swap the `r` and `c` loops for a good speed boost (noticeable only with larger images):

```
for c=1:sizeColsOut
    c_in = (c-1)*S;
    for r=1:sizeRowsOut
        r_in = (r-1)*S;
```

---

Finally the bit inside the main double loop: It is more complicated than it needs to be because of the loop. In MATLAB you don't need it:

```
sampleWindow = input(r_in+(1:F),c_in+(1:F));
dotProd = sum(sampleWindow(:) .* kernelf(:));
```

or simply:

```
dotProd = dot(sampleWindow(:), kernelf(:));
```

or even:

```
dotProd = sampleWindow(:).' * kernelf(:);
```

But if you want to write out the inner loop as well, I recommend that you don't copy out a piece of the image, but access the data in the image directly:

```
dotProd = 0;
for jj=1:F
    for ii=1:F
        dotProd = dotProd + input(r_in+ii,c_in+jj) * kernelf(ii,jj);
    end
end
```

This is much cleaner and readable (IMO) because there are fewer variables to keep track of.

---

Oh, and one more issue: color images. If `depthInput>1`, then you read from the first channel, and write to the last channel. You are not doing color processing at all!

Because the color dimension is stored last, the most efficient thing to do is to call this gray-value convolution once for each color channel.

Comment: Thank you Chris, this was both very helpful and very well presented, a great teaching moement. the reason I had a loop for the dotProd was for hardware code generation since those functions aren't supported, and for the depth channels I decided just to handle them on the main function instead.